# The type 'FlexIT.MainActivity' must provide a public default constructor in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

```
namespace FlexIT
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = false)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected MainActivity(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code this say the error is The type 'FlexIT.MainActivity' must provide a public default constructor

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the below codes:

```
protected MainActivity(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
 {
 }
```

So your MainActivity will like this:

```
namespace FlexIT
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = false)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

}